# Convert to int from String of numbers having comma

Tags: java

I have value like this:

```
String x = "10,000";
```

I want to convert this to `int`.
I can convert it by removing comma like below:

```
String y = x.replace(",", "");
int value1 = Integer.parseInt(y);
```

But I don't want to do it like above.

Any other suggestions like inbuilt function? Or any other recommended ways for this?

Comment: What stopping you to do this ?>

Answer (score 15):

You can simply:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.UK).parse(x);
```

Read about:

- [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)
- [`Locale.UK`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#UK) and others.

Comment: @grimmeld So what is your way of solution ?

Comment: @grimmeld I thought OP want's to parse it as 10, corrected. Usually, I expect OP to investigate more when providing an answer, he might try all `Locale`s available. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);    
 Number number = format.parse("10,000"); 

 // Now you can get number values from the object (like int, long, double)
 System.out.println(number.intValue());
```

Output:

> 10000

Note: If you string contains values after decimal point, you need to use `number.doubleValue` to retain the precision because `number.intValue()` will simply ignore values after decimal points.

Comment: but it contains character like 8,0bc,1,a it won't throw any exception.I want to handle as string if it contains chars

Answer (score 0):

Use any one of these:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).parse("10,000").intValue();
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).parse("10,000").intValue();
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.UK).parse("10,000").intValue();
```

Comment: But if  it contains character like "8,0bc,1,a" it won't throw any exception.I want to handle as string if it contains chars other than ',' & numbers.