# java: how to ensure that a number is formatted in a certain locale

Tags: java

I'm trying to decide what is the best way to test if a given text is a number formatted. Started based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880563/convert-to-int-from-string-of-numbers-having-comma%20);

Is this possible using locales? Or do I need to use some regular expression?

my code is something like this but it does not really work as expected

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

  public static boolean isFormatted (String number, Locale locale) {
    try {
      NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).parse(number);
      return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isFormatted ("3a", Locale.US));    // expected false // actual true
    System.out.println(isFormatted ("3000", Locale.US));  // expected false // actual true
    System.out.println(isFormatted ("3,000", Locale.US)); // expected true  // actual true
    System.out.println(isFormatted ("300", Locale.US));   // expected true  // actual true
  }
}
```

thanks for any feedback

edit1: based on a feedback from a comment that was deleted I guess the best solution could be:

first get the string and convert to a number
then using the local convert the number back to a string and compare the 2 strings.
would this be the best solution?

edit2: put the question into a code example to hopefully explain better
edit3: based on the feedback this would be my way of fixing it

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

  public static boolean isFormatted (final String number, final Locale locale) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
    try {
      long amount = nf.parse(number).longValue();
      if (nf.format(amount).equals(number) ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isFormatted ("3a", Locale.US));    // expected false
    System.out.println(isFormatted ("3000", Locale.US));  // expected false
    System.out.println(isFormatted ("3,000", Locale.US)); // expected true
    System.out.println(isFormatted ("300", Locale.US));   // expected true
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you know what locale you should be using?  Also, from a math point of view, none of this should matter, right?

Comment: What is the exact error for "does not really work"?

Comment: Dont add such information in comments. Clearly describe **expected** and **actual** behavior of your code **in** your question. So please: delete the comments and improve the question to be a full [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would statically declare the allowed formats and have it parse the String

```
class MyParser {
    private static final NumberFormat TARGET_FORMAT = 
        new DecimalFormat(Locale.US); // just as an example
    private static final NumberFormat[] ALLOWED = {
        TARGET_FORMAT,
        new DecimalFormat("#,###.") // just as an example
    };

    public Optional<Double> parse(String toParse) {
        for (NumberFormat f : ALLOWED) {
            try {
                double d = f.parse(toParse).doubleValue();
                return Optional.of(d);
            } catch (ParseException e) {}
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public boolean isProperlyFormatted(String input) {
        return parse(input).isPresent();
    }

    /** Format a value to a proper format */
    public String format(double d) {
        return TARGET_FORMAT.format("%f", d);
    }

    public Optional<String> reformat(String input) {
        return parse(input).map(format);
    }
}
```

So to test if a String is properly formatted:

```
if (myParser.isProperlyFormatted(input)) {
    // properly formatted
}
```

if you have a value you want to display

```
System.out.println(myParser.format(value));
```

and to make sure you have a properly formatted value

```
// will be Optional.empty() if original string wasn't formatted properly
myParser.reformat(string);
```

Comment: thanks, i was thinking something like that would be the best way, I was just trying to build a simple example where I can unit test this and just updated my code. will now try your solution

Comment: I did something a bit more easy based on your reply. I'll mark it as answered now.
I think maybe my question was a bit ambiguous at the beginning